# Excel VBA loop through data validation options and save as new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. For this project I am focusing in on one sheet called "Report 3".  On this sheet, there is a data validation cell ("N12"), populated by values on a different sheet.

My goal is to loop through all possible values of the data validation cell and save each of these as a new workbook.  If possible, I would like to save it as a utf-16 txt file (but I haven't gotten that far in my code).

Here is the code I have so far. It works, but only for the first value of the data validation. My hunch is that it is getting tripped up on ActiveWorkbook.

I appreciate any insight and assistance.

```
Sub loopthroughvalidationlist()

Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("N12").Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    Dim s As String
    s = Cells(12, "N").Value & "postran"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & s
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? That should be a backslash if yes.

Comment: @dwirony I'm on a mac. Should it still be a backslash?

Comment: No a forward slash is correct then. I don't understand what you're trying to do here - what purpose does `c` serve in your `For Each` loop?

Comment: @dwirony the c is supposed to represent each of the options in the data validation dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub loopthroughvalidationlist()

Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("N12").Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    Cells(12, "N").Value = c.Value
    Dim s As String
    s = Cells(12, "N").Value & "postran"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & s
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! So I basically needed to reset the c value within the for loop? Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of - you were iterating through a collection of the data validation items, but you needed to actually change the cell's value each time in your loop.